# How can I capture the tooltip values of an SVG image using selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

From this website:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/index

how can you capture the tooltip value when you hover over a single bar of the SVG image?

Comment: I tried xpath but after I did more reading, that was not looking like the right solution. I think the solution is somewhere with actions or javascript but I'm not sure. I'm in a java environment with webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do a few things...

1. Wait for the graph to draw
2. Hover over the desired bar (specified by `barIndex`)
3. Wait for the tooltip to appear
4. Grab the text from the tooltip

I tested the code below.

```
int barIndex = 3;
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/index");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("g[clip-path] path")));
List<WebElement> bars = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("g[clip-path] path"));
System.out.println(bars.size());
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(bars.get(barIndex)).build().perform();
WebElement tooltip = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.k-tooltip.k-chart-tooltip")));
System.out.println(tooltip.getText().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you mouserover the chart, a `div` with `class=k-tooltip k-chart-tooltip` is becomes visible. after you mouseover code, run followiwng code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("k-tooltip k-chart-tooltip")).getText();
```